# Run-time error 1004 when using Auto_Open() in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

So I've created a simple macro that loops through all worksheets and AutoFits all columns. It works when I run it manually but I want it to run each time I launch Excel automatically. I placed it in a module and named the sub `Auto_Open()`. The problem is that I'm getting

> "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Worksheets' of object '_Global' failed."

each time I start up Excel now.

Here's the code. The debugger says its the `For Each` portion that is causing the problem but I don't understand why. What am I missing? Thanks for any help.

```
Sub AUTO_OPEN()
'
' AutoFit_All_Columns Macro
'

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: This won't stop the error which I think has been answered already, but I'd remove `UsedRange` as that could return an incorrect range - just use `ws.Columns.AutoFit` to reference all columns on the sheet (any blank columns shouldn't be affected).

Answer (score 3):

`For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`

Comment: @BigBen The problem with `Me` is that it will only refer to `ThisWorkbook` if it's used in the `ThisWorkbook` module.  In a worksheet it will refer to the worksheet, in a form to the form, in a normal module it returns an error, in a class it returns the class.  As I read on a Chandoo page:  _Me refers to the parent object from which the code is "sitting" in_.  `ThisWorkbook` on the other hand _always_ refers to the workbook that the code is in.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook my bad, I was thinking of a `Workbook_Open` residing in the `ThisWorkbook` module, instead of `Auto_Open`, which I tend to shy away from using.

Comment: I thought `Auto_Open` was a legacy command and `Workbook_Open` is the preferred method.  Can't remember using `Auto_Open` before.  I was reading it as a `Workbook_Open` event and I'd still argue that `ThisWorkbook` would be preferred - `Me` limits where you can put the code, while `ThisWorkbook` would allow me to pull the AutoFit procedure into a standalone procedure that I can call from anywhere.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I can see the merits of that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I replaced it with ThisWorkbook.Worksheets but now it doesn't seem to be AutoFitting the columns anymore even if I manually run it. The error message did however go away. I wouldn't mind using Workbook_Open instead but I could not figure out how to have it automatically run on any and all Excel files. I'm wanting this to affect any spreadsheet that I might look at.

Comment: I get the feeling that it might be running but it doesnt **look** like it's doing anything because depending on how your data looks `AutoFit` might not actually change the column's size

Comment: I believe it's because it's trying to apply the AutoFit to the Personal.XLSB workbook instead of the one that I double-clicked on. The columns of the workbook that I opened myself are definitely not resizing when using "ThisWorkbook.Worksheets".

Comment: @Wolvman you can change `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` to `Workbooks("yourworkbookname").Worksheets`

Comment: Is there a way to have it automatically replace "yourworkbookname" with whatever the current workbook name is that I double-clicked on?

Comment: @Wolvman Not exactly sure what you mean here by "double-clicked on" ? Are you keeping this macro in a separate workbook and wanting to resize other workbooks you open?

Comment: Yes, the macro was placed in the modules section of the built-in PERSONAL.XLSB workbook. I read that using Sub Auto_Open() in there would allow the macro to run for any workbooks that I opened (double-clicked on). The goal is to just have any spreadsheet that I ever open automatically AutoFit the columns without me having to touch anything.

Comment: @Wolvman you can look into `Application.RecentFiles(1)` to get last opened workbook

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `ActiveWorkbook`. Try this code :

```
Sub AUTO_OPEN()
    '
    ' AutoFit_All_Columns Macro
    '

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: I gave this a shot as well. The macro still works when I run it manually but now when I open up a file in Excel it gives me a different error. "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set."

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative using the Workbook_Open method that seems to work just fine. Placing this in the "ThisWorkbook" portion of the built-in Personal VBAProject will run AutoFit on all columns automatically when any workbook is opened.

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal WB As Workbook)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In WB.Worksheets
        ws.Columns.AutoFit
    Next ws

End Sub
```